# Display different data according to category

Tags: magento2

I am displaying data on my front end on configurable products. But I am getting the same data for all products. Can anyone tell me how to change data according to the specific category?

**Suppose for Men's, one thing should be displayed for Women other.**

Can anyone suggest me anything good???
 I am using Magento 2.2.5

Comment: Have you confirm that, your product is assign to only 1 category?

Comment: what will be source of your data ?

Comment: @Pawan I have added a button on my all configurable products. and the data is text(WYSIWYG). I have created a block class for that button. In it i am getting my custom collection. using `addFieldToSelect()`. by this it is displaying all the data from my custom table. If i give him `addFieldToFilter()` and custom ID is given it works okay. but i want it to work according to core category. how can i target the core category of men/women. **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Always Provide the code which you have written so that someone can identify any issue in your code

you can Use following code

```
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $_categoryFactory


      $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
    $cats    = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (count($cats)) {

        $firstCategoryId = $cats[$pos];
        $_category       = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($firstCategoryId);
        return $_category->getName();
    }
```

Please Note : You can loop through the categories to find all categories. In my code I m trying to fetch only the first category